# ERROR 000210 Cannot create output 'name' Failed to execute CopyFeatures

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, error-000210

I'm learning ArcPy, when I run this code from Python on ArcMap it works. But it does not work from the separate Python shell.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os
output_dir = "C:/Data"
env.workspace = os.path.join(output_dir, "Output.gdb")
env.overwriteOutput = True   

output_features = "name"
origins = "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.5\ArcCatalog\Connection to sde.sde\SDE.tablename" 

arcpy.management.CopyFeatures(origins, output_features)
```

I'm getting arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output 'name' Failed to execute (CopyFeatures).

Comment: Please [edit] the question in response to requests for clarification or answers that don't solve your issue. You have a glaring naming bug (failure to use double-backslash or the *raw* formatting prefix (`r"C:\foo"`) but it seems there are multiple issues, so you should update your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't defined a workspace for your output, just a basename. If you run your script in ArcGIS, arcpy will use the default workspace defined at the application level. But this won't work outside ArcGIS.
Either

- use `arcpy.env.workspace` (e.g. `arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Data\gdb.gdb`) in the beginning of your script to set the workspace,
- or set the full path to your output (e.g. `output_features 
  = r"C:\Data\gdb.gdb\name"`)

Note that the workspace (folder or gdb) must exist, it won't be created by Copy Features.

Comment: I added workspace to the code, still having the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the workspace exists?

Answer (score 0):

You need to deal with the backslash which has special meaning to Python.  I recommend using an `r` to treat it as a raw string.

```
origins = "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.5\ArcCatalog\Connection to sde.sde\SDE.tablename"
```

should be:

```
origins = r"C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.5\ArcCatalog\Connection to sde.sde\SDE.tablename"
```